# Q Simplify LHS to match the RHS of this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{(2^{a+1})+(-1)^a}{3 \cdot 2^{a+1}}+(1/2)^{a+1}  =\frac{2^{a+2} -(- 1)^{a+1} }{3 \cdot 2^{a+1}}$$

Can someone please explain how I go about simplifying the LHS so it looks like the RHS.

Also if possible point me to other examples that are similar so I can get the hand of it.

Comment: For $a=0$ you get $\,1=5/6\,$ so the two sides are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides by the denominator.

$2^{a+1}+(-1)^a+3=2^{a+2}-(-1)^{a+1}=2^{a+2}-(-1)(-1^a)=2^{a+2}+(-1^a)$

$2^{a+1}+3=2^{a+2}$

$3=2^{a+1}(2-1)=2^{a+1}$

By The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, there are no integer solutions for $a$. The expressions are never equal.

Comment: Could someone correct if I wrong but do you not work on the LHS only so you get the form of the RHS.

Comment: If the sides aren't equal, it doesn't matter, really. If they are equal its okay to work with both sides as "scratch work". You work on LHS to get some expression, then you work on the RHS in isolation to get the same expression. Once you have overlap, you can usually work backwards through the RHS steps to complete a proof strictly via operations on LHS.  True, your final proof of equivalence you probably do only want to work on a single side.